# R load shapefile: "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values"

Tags: r, plot, shapefile

I've created the following script to get the coastline of Denmark

```
# Get Shapefiles for Coastline
shpurl <- "http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/denmark-latest.shp.zip"
tmp <- tempfile(fileext=".zip")
download.file(shpurl, destfile = tmp)
files <- unzip(tmp, exdir=getwd())

# Load & plot shapefile
library(maptools)
shp <- readShapePoly(files[grep(".shp$", shpurl)])
plot(shp)
```

This should give me the outline of Denmark, however, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any help or directions is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try any [other ways](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles) of reading shapefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your `files` value:

```
> length(files)
[1] 41
```

The files you are downloading have number of shape files for various geographies. For instance the code:

```
require(rgdal)
shp <- readOGR(dsn = "whereIsavedyourStuff/Stacks", layer = "roads")
```

will execute properly. But you will need to specify, which of the sourced shape files you want to read.

---

As a side point, with respect to reading files from the net, I would suggest that you have a look at this code:

```
# Download an read US state shapefiles
tmp_shps <- tempfile(); tmp_dir <- tempdir()
download.file("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_state_20m.zip",
              tmp_shps)
unzip(tmp_shps, exdir = tmp_dir)

# Libs
require(rgdal)

# Read
us_shps <- readOGR(dsn = tmp_dir, layer = "cb_2014_us_state_20m")
```

Irrespectively, of what method to read shape files you decide to use you have to specify path and file name. In terms of the provided code in `readOGR` this is fulfilled by `dns` and `layer` options. In your code you used `files[grep(".shp$", shpurl)]`, file names within your **195MB** archive, do not corresponds to the URL. You have a few options here:

1. You can download this files and unpack as you did, list names of all the files that are `*.shp`, take the file names and pass them in the loop to a list where you would read all combinations (in effect you need a number of files to *read* each layer)
2. Better, specify the layer you want to read similarly to the code provided above.